# The statement works in SQL Query but not work in stored procedure

Tags: sql, location

I'm trying to monitor and collect data changes on a table, When I make query to this table I get this error:

> Not found: Dataset myporject-dev:streaming was not found in location EU
> at [myporject-dev.myporject-dev2.scan_streaming_testing_table_raw:5:5]

I had tested the SQL query in myporject-dev2, it works fine:

```
SELECT
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS monitor_triggered, 
    COUNT(1) AS detect_row_count,
    MIN(id) AS id, 
    MIN(ingestion_timestamp) AS ingestion_timestamp, 
    MIN(_uuid) AS _uuid
FROM
    `myporject-dev.streaming.testing_table_raw` AS A
WHERE 
    ingestion_timestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 day) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
```

2. Then created a test table and a stored procedure in another myporject-dev2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myporject-dev2.scan_streaming_testing_table_raw()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dm_data_quality.test_streaming_raw_tab_mon(monitor_triggered, detect_row_count, id, ingestion_timestamp, _uuid)
    select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as monitor_triggered, count(1) as detect_row_count
      ,min(id) as id, min(ingestion_timestamp) as ingestion_timestamp, min(_uuid) as _uuid
from   `myporject-dev.streaming.testing_table_raw` as A
where ingestion_timestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 day) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
END;
```

3. Call the stored procedure myproject:

   dev2.scan_streaming_testing_table_raw(), it raises the error:

   > call myporject-dev2.scan_streaming_testing_table_raw();
   > Not found: Dataset myporject-dev:streaming was not found in location EU
   > at [myporject-dev.myporject-dev2.scan_streaming_testing_table_raw:5:5]

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms used, to get appropriate attention.

Comment: You quite often use `myporject` which seems to be a typo for `myproject` - is it just a matter of spelling the procedure name correctly?